# Nullable Map mapping in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map entity-key with entity-value map to database using JPA2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.7.
Here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Audited
class Form{

    //id

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "form_content",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_form", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_field_content"/*non-working part start*/, unique = false, nullable = true/*non-working part stop*/),
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id_field", "id_form" }) })
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_field", nullable = false)
    private Map<FormEntryDefinition, FormEntryValue> content;

    //getters, setters, equals, etc.
}
```

Hibernate generates table

```
form_content(
    id_form bigint primary key not null,
    id_field_content bigint <!-- problem start -->not null unique <!--problem stop -->,
    id_field bigint primary key not null)
```

with proper foreign keys in all 3 fields.

Could anyone tell me, why hibernate generates unique and not null constraints, so I can't persist map with nullable value?

Is there any workaround for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

The unique constraint is due to using a `@OneToMany` association. If you change it to `@ManyToMany` then the unique constraint would no longer be necessary.

The join table FK columns only make sense for non-nullable columns. A row in the join table is a link between two tables, and if one FK is missing then the association breaks anyway and it's equivalent to not having a link row in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I changed associaton to ManyToMany, but Hibernate still creates not null column. It seems like any relationship created with Hibernate has to be 1 to 1 or 1 to {1-*} or {1-*} to {1-*} but I want to create 1 to {0-1} in my case. To be more specific, I need 1 [form] associated with multiple of (1[entry] to {0-1}[optional value]).

Comment: The ManyToMany was for unique not for not-null. For 1-to-{0-1} you don't need a JoinTable. You need a parent table and a child table having a FK to the parent table PK. You can map that with a OneToOne association. If there's a child record then you have a 1-to-1, otherwise you have a 1-to-0. The child must be the owner of the association while the parent uses mappedBy.

Comment: OK, but how to put it into the map? As You can see, I want to have multiple forms with multiple entry definitions with optional value for that definitions. In other words, each instance of entry definition could have different value in each form, so I can't create just 1-to-1 association between entry definition and entry value. I can create map(form,value) in FormEntryDefinition class, but it would be still map with nullable value, that I cannot create using JPA.

Comment: So is JPA breaking the Java Map contract by not allowing null values?